# Calculation of the sequence with fixed modulus

Tags: algorithms, modular-arithmetic

I'm studying about the modular multiplication and I woner if there is an algorithm to calculate the any long sequence (for example, $0$ to $10^{10}$) with fixed modulus (for example, modulus 9 as below) in a polynomial time.

[image]

Comment: What is it you are trying to calculate?  As you surmise, arithmetic $\pmod 9$ is pretty simple...

Comment: I'm trying to make a quantum computing algorithm and I need to know if there is an algorithm to calculate the a very long sequence with fixed modulus in a polynomial time, not like the above figure where it is just only from 0 to 17.

Comment: Well, again.  Arithmetic $\pmod 9$ is very simple.  You just need to take the remainder on division by $9$.

Comment: Do you want to know the value of $10^{10}\mod 9$ in poly time, or generate the entire sequence from $0$ to $10^{10}$ in poly time?

Comment: You understand, the sequence is periodic.  Sure, printing the first $10^{10}$ values is hard but do you really need to do that?  It's hard to print a single character $10^{10}$ times...

Comment: @wjmccann,  The entire sequence. I just wonder if there is like that kind of algorithm that can calculate the entire sequence in poly time, whatever the range is.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to generate the sequence $0$ to $10^n$ $\mod k$ for some particular values of $n, k$. The sequence of values mod some number is periodic, as
$$
x\equiv x+k \mod k
$$
So starting at $0$ the sequence is just going to be
$$
0,1,2,3,4,\ldots,k,0,1,2,3,\ldots, k,0,1,2\ldots
$$

In theory you can just print this out for every number and that would be $\mathcal{O}(10^n)$ which is exponential with respect to the digits of $10^n$ (although polynomial with respect to the value).

Comment: What if I calculate the sequcne of A*x mod N where x is from 0 to N and A is any positive integer? We can find the period of this function at a certain point (from 0 to A*k) even though that certain point would be exponential. Is there any way to calculate it in poly time?

Comment: If $A$ is fixed then it is still periodic in $k$, so the same method would apply. Do the first $k$ and then repeat from there.

Comment: Yeah I understand the logic, but I wonder if the calculation until reaching the first k would be done in poly time in any cases. Do you have no idea about it?

Comment: You just loop through and do the calculation for the first $k$. This is linear wrt numerical value of $k$, but exponential with digits of $k$. This is a lower bound, as you must generate an item for every value (even if you don't explicitly calculate it). So this is poly time in a way, and is the best you can do

Comment: Very helpful comment. Thank you so much!